# Printing using libusb

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, libusb

Hello I am working on project that need to print directly to USB printer (POS printer). The application is running on Linux, right now i am using the usblp to print by write ESCP command directly to /dev/usb/lp0. Everything goes well, but the problem comes when user plug a printer that not detected as usblp on Linux.

So instead of depends on linux kernel usblp, I would like to directly write the data to USB device using libusb. So my question will be:

1. Is it OK to send directly the ESCP command to printer using libusb.
2. From the libusb docs, to open and configure usb device there are some step to do. Should I open and configure the usb when printing OR I open and configure once and keep it open so I don't need to open and close when I want to print?
3. If I want to open and close printer when I want print, is it fast for opening, configure, and claiming an USB device using libusb?

Comment: 1. Yes you can send ESCP command to printer. Our project at www.kassaku.nl can print to many printers at the same time and reroute to another printer in case of problems. We do not use libusb, but want to see next month if that is faster than ::write(). I could send you some files, but they are too big for stackoverflow. If you send me your e-mail, I will reply some classes to help you. (maybe too late)